# Autorun Excel / Macro on schedule

Tags: excel, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a workbook that contains a macro that I would like to run once a week automatically.

I have set up the workbook_open event to run the macro and the code itself runs as I would like it to.

My question is how to schedule this to automatically run on a schedule. I have setup a task in windows task scheduler which does not seem to run reliably (i've tried this on a few different projects over the years and never get great results).

My desire is to have my personal desktop run this task whether or not I am logged in. (Obviously the computer needs to be powered on which is no problem. Also, I am the only one that uses this computer, no concern about someone else being logged in)

Is there a more robust way of doing this or am I stuck with task scheduler? If so, has anyone else had better success with it that might be able to help me out?

Task scheduler seems to work only intermittently although the "history" shows it is triggered and run at the desired times. Part of the code saves a file to a location with a date stamp and there are not files for each trigger in the scheduler history.

[image: Scheduler_Trigger]

[image: Task_settings]

[image: Task_Conditions]

[image: Task_History]

[image: Files_Created]

Answer (score 0):

When logged off , the task is executed without loading the user profile.

Maybe this is the answer for you.
It's Japanese. Can you use google translate?

[enter link description here](http://gagaj.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/03/21/162218)

You have to make the directory.
If you use 32bit Excel : %SystemRoot%\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
If you use 64bit Excel : %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might run across this. I've been using a 3rd party task scheduler which is much more reliable in my experience. There are many out there but i use robointern.  [robointern website](https://robointern.tech/)